# How to Reversegeoforwading when based on item selected from the search display controller results

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller, mkreversegeocoder

Hi I would like to Reversegeo of the selected destination results to current. My Reversegeoforwading function will draw the poly line between the two points and calculate distance.

[image: screenshot]

Currently I call the function on search query which is making a mess doing multiple revergeoforwarding before the user select the autocomplete result prediction.

I tried to call the revergeoforwarding function tableview didselectitematindex method but doesn't get called.  How can I Reversegeoforwad only when the user has selected an item from the tableview of search display controller?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well i figured it out on my own, this is a great learning curve for me to develop my first iOS app.

Put in did

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self requestForwardGeoCoding:[self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath].name];
}
```